# Take alt tag from image and place into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying desperately to clone an alt tag, and append it to a sibling div. I'm close I think, but I think I'm missing a key feature.

```
<div class="project_tile">
<p>
<a class="blog_thumb" href="/work?title=personal-trainer-website-design">
<img src="img_cms/projects/thumb-revolution_230x276.jpg" width="263" height="121" alt="Personal Trainer Website Design">
<div class="hover"></div>
</a>
</p>
</div>
```

trying to take the alt tag and append it to div.hover

```
$(".project_tile p .hover").html( $(".project_tile p img").attr("alt") );
```

There are a series of sibling .project_tiles in a container all with the same markup (but diifferent images with different alt tags)

The alt tag from the first image is transferring to ALL the project tiles, but just need it to clone it to the .hover in the same .project_tile...

hover a project tile here http://fifteenten.s1lver.co.uk/work to see what I'm on about

I'll be damned if I can figure how to limit it to 'this' project tile... though I'm sure the word 'this' needs to be used somewhere...

any help massively appreciated as always!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple `project_tile` elements then you need to find the relative `alt` value, in this case the `img` is the previous sibling of the `.hover` element.

So try

```
$(".project_tile p .hover").html(function () {
    return $(this).prev().attr('alt')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JfC6N/)

Comment: +1. Or to allow for potential minor structure changes: `$(this).closest(".project_tile").find("img").attr("alt")`.

Comment: Also have these javascript bits affecting project_tile?

 $('.project_tile a p').append('<div class="hover">');
 
 $(".project_tile p .hover").html(function () {
  return $(this).prev().attr('alt')
 });
 
 $('.project_tile a p').hover( 
 function() {$(this).children('div').fadeIn('fast');}, 
 function() {$(this).children('div').fadeOut('fast');}
 )